# Matching intervals between pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, intervals, matching

I have two dataframes. The first one (file_1), containing an ID column and depth from and depth to

```
           ID  Depth_From  Depth_To 
0      HLD032      611.10    612.00  
1      HLD032      612.00    612.20   
2      HLD032      612.20    614.80  
3      HLD032      614.80    616.20 
4      HLD032      616.20    617.80
...        ...         ...       ...  
10082  HLD650      594.80    596.50      
10083  HLD650      596.50    597.40        
10084  HLD650      597.40    598.10
```

The second dataframe (file_2), containing an ID column, depth from and depth to and some parameters (Infill, Roughness, Thickness)

```
            ID  Depth_From  Depth_To Infill Roughness  Thickness
0       HLD032      681.30   681.301    Qtz         R        0.5
1       HLD032      681.37   681.371    Qtz         R        0.5
2       HLD032      681.50   681.501    Qtz         R        0.5
3       HLD032      682.15   682.151    Qtz         R        0.5
4       HLD032      682.71   682.711    Qtz         R        0.5
...        ...         ...       ...    ...       ...        ...
125219  HLD650      569.95   569.970    Qtz         R       24.0
125220  HLD650      573.08   573.090    Qtz         R        5.0
125221  HLD650      588.97   588.980    Qtz         R       10.0
```

What I need is to create match for each ID and for each interval (depth from, depth to) for file_1 the correspondent parameters (Infill, Roughness, Thickness) in the second dataframe (file_2).

As more than one value for each parameters will correspond to each interval, I want a column like

```
            ID  Depth_From  Depth_To Infill             Roughness  Thickness
0       HLD032      611.10    612.00     Qtz, Qtz, Qtz    R,R,R,K   0.3,0.10.5
1       HLD032      681.37   681.371    Qtz, Chl,Chl      S,R,R   0.1.0.2,0.5
2       HLD032      681.50   681.501    Qtz,Btz,Lm       R,Y,Y        0.5,3,1
```

Anyone is able to help me?

Comment: Hello? Is anyone interested to help me? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you will be able to take advantage of this solution with data I created:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
                    'From': [1, 3, 5, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                    'To': [4, 6, 6, 9, 3, 4, 7, 6]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 1, 2],
                    'From': [3, 5, 5],
                    'To': [4, 6, 6],
                    'Value': [5,10,15]})

df1['Value'] = df1.apply(lambda x: ', '.join(df2.loc[(df2['ID']==x['ID'])& \
                                                    (df2['From']>=x['From'])& \
                                                    (df2['To']<=x['To']), 'Value'].astype(str).tolist()), axis=1)
df1
#   From  ID  To  Value
#0     1   1   4      5
#1     3   1   6  5, 10
#2     5   1   6     10
#3     7   1   9       
#4     1   2   3       
#5     2   2   4       
#6     3   2   7     15
#7     4   2   6     15
```

Comment: Thanks zipa. I’ll give it a go when I go home at let you know 

Comment: @Tani84 You are welcome, this principle should do the job for you, although there must be a better solution speed-wise

Comment: Perfect.It works. Just another adjustment. If I want to select a specific value in the list. In your example between 5 and 10 I want the value to be 10